# Set focus to first empty input or textarea in a Form

Tags: jquery

I want to set focus to the first empty input or textarea element, **in a Form**

I know that the following jQuery code sets focus to the first input or textarea on a page but how do i limit it to a specific form?

```
$("textarea:empty,input:text[value='']").first().focus();
```

Comment: you can do on load event of the window.
 `window.onload = function(e) {
                $("textarea:empty,input:text[value='']").first().focus();
            };`

Comment: This would still put focus on the first empty element on the page but I want to limit it to a specific form. There could be elements above this form but they are not relevant and I don't want focus on them.

Comment: You can add formId in that code itself like `$("#yourformid textarea:empty,input:text[value='']").first().focus();`

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me Kiran. I see that someone gave it a 'useful comment' vote and it feels like it should work, but for some reason it didn't. But thank you for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just target your form first and then [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the first empty element inside the form:

`$("#your-form").find("textarea:empty,input:text[value='']").first().focus();`

this focuses the first empty field inside a form with id `your-form` :

```html
<form id="your-form">
 ...
</form>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Kiran's suggestion did not work.
I did however have another problem. The form is created dynamically and when a field had a NULL value the input tag did not get a value attribute. But when I solved this you code worked like a charm, thanks a lot!